# jquery-ui selectmenu as a link?

Tags: jquery-ui

We have the following HTML:

```
<option value="4def1b88a1247"><a href="link">Text</a></option>
```

When using jquery-ui select menu, the option is changed to:

```
<span class="ui-selectmenu-status">Text</span>
```

How do we get a jquery-ui selectmenu option to link to another page? We have tried onclick, but this also gets removed when the select menu is re-written.

We just want our options to link to pages without the need of a form to be submitted, is this possible with jquery-ui selectmenu?

Comment: Sorry, this is what we are using: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Comment: Yes Cold, that is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your select element:

```
<select id="my_menu">
    <option value="/page1.html">Go to Page 1</option>
    <option value="/page2.html">Go to Page 2</option>
</select>
```

And then use the change event to fire the link:

```
$('#my_menu').selectmenu({
    change: function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            window.location = $(this).val();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: direction is no valid option (and irrelevant to this question), but change callback is the best possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation here, https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu, there are callback events that can be used.  You mentioned that you tried onclick...perhaps using the change and select callbacks will work instead?

The documentation is from the Felix Nagel version of the plugin by the way, which the FilamentGroup people say on their page is an improved version of there's.